# Why is my server getting stuck on recvfrom()? (UDP socket)

Tags: c, sockets

I'm required to make a 'height sensing subsystem' to read the data sent from a moonlander by making a UDP protocol. The client is already set up for me, and is a 64bit executable on linux run by using `./simulator`. So I need to make the UDP server in linux to connect with the client.

The client sends readings from many subsystems in the moonlander, but I only need to read one of them, which is the laser altimeter reading that corresponds to the a type specified by 0xaa01, there are other types such as `0xaa##`, and `0xff##`, but those correspond to different subsystems of the moonlander I assume. The data sent from the `./simulator` file is sent through the type, which I then need to decode to find if its the laser altimeter, and then I need to decode the values to convert into distance to find when the moonlander has touched down. I need to read the time first, which has a size of 4 bytes and is an unsigned 32 bit integer, and the laser altimeter reading is 3 unsigned 16-bit integers that correspond to 3 different measurements (as there are 3 different sensors on the altimeter, max height of 1000m, convert by dividing by 65.535 which is `UINT16_MAX`, and multiplying by 100 to convert to cm). I need to then take those readings, convert them into height, and then acknowledge that we've landed once we've hit 40cm away from the ground.

How do I read the data from the `./simulator` file? The problem is that when I run the `./receiver` file, it stops working at the recvfrom() function as in my code below. In the instructions, they tell me to connect to port 12778, which works, but I'm not receiving anything.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


// Create a UDP datagram socket
int main() {
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        perror("Can't connect");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    addr.sin_family = AF_INET; // use IPv4
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; // bind to all interfaces
    addr.sin_port = htons(12778); // the port we want to bind

    // Bind to the port specified above
    if (bind(fd, (const struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror("cant connect");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("here");
    // Listen for data on our port (this is blocking)
    char buffer[4096];
    
    int n = recvfrom(fd, buffer, 4096, MSG_WAITALL, NULL, NULL);
    printf("Recieved!"); 
}
```

Comment: There can be many reasons, chief amongst them is that UDP gives you no guarantees, whatsoever, that any sent UDP packet will ever be received.

Comment: Run wireshark/tcpdump to confirm that `simulator` is indeed sending what you think it should be to the port and IP that you expect.

Comment: Also, write your own simple server to test the client. The point is - troubleshoot and debug the problem by trying to isolate where the issue may be.

Comment: your call to `recvfrom` is blocking, so it is not stuck it is waiting for the data to be received. you should try what the others have proposed and see if the system actually receives the data or not

Comment: Send local test packets, e.g. with `socat - UDP-SENDTO:localhost:12778` and check if they are received. Dump traffic with `tcpdump -i any udp port 12778` and check if packets from client really are reaching your host. Btw, `MSG_WAITALL` in flags is useless, it is not supported for UDP.

Comment: The `MSG_WAITALL` flag tells `recvfrom()` to block until the full 4096 bytes have been received. Try replacing it with `0`. Also, you should print the value of `n` to see how many bytes were received. Btw., you should write in the question which systems it concerns since some behaviour may be depending on the OS.

Comment: It worked! I ran it on vmware with ubuntu and it just worked for some reason. Who knows why but I'm not complaining